# How to output 2 commands in 1 text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

Greeting all,

I have been browsing the Q&A but cant find any way to do this. Basically I wanted to get the result of 2 syntax in 1 text file.

here is the part of XML:

```
<JOB PRO_JOB="D6C1608493" XMLMODE="REPORT">

<SAMPLE CUID="0001347496" SAMPLETYPE="OTHER" SAMPLEIDENT="1608493-2" SAMPLETIME="18/09/2016 2300">

    <SCHEME SCH_CODE="/CSA" SCHEMETYPE="ANALYS">


        <ANALYTE ANALYTECODE="S" ANALYTENAME="S" TAG="FEED1" NUMERICVALUE="1.019999980926514" ROUNDEDVALUE="1.02">
        </ANALYTE>
        </SCHEME>
</SAMPLE>
```

So in when i try to execute command in powershell:`$doc.job.sample.scheme.analyte` it gives me the result for Analyte which is fine, but i want to also get the result to get the result of command`$doc
.job.sample` in 1 output text file. was able to output it but only with 1 command.

side question: how do I get to display only the SAMPLETIME value when I execute`$doc1.job.sample`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're missing a closing tag on `<JOB>`, so I'm going to assume there's one at the end of the document. I'm also assuming you're loading the XML some way similar to this:

```
$doc = [xml](Get-Content '.\samples.xml')
```

I'm guessing that the way you're outputting the information to the file is with the redirection operator `>`. As you've likely discovered, that blows away any existing contents of the target file. You can append to the file, however, with `>>`. Therefore, you might do something like this:

```
$doc.JOB.SAMPLE.SCHEME.ANALYTE > outfile.txt
$doc.JOB.SAMPLE >> outfile.txt
```

If you want to get the value of an attribute, you can just treat the attribute as another child object on its owning element's object. This prints what you want to the screen; you can redirect it as appropriate:

```
$doc.JOB.SAMPLE.SAMPLETIME
```

Comment: Thank you, you are correct there is a </Job> missing at the end. Also, your solution is much more elegant and simple i guess. coz I tried doing this: PS C:\> $doc.job.sample[0] | Out-File C:\xml\test.txt {ascii}

PS C:\> $doc.job.sample.scheme.analyte | Out-File C:\xml\test.txt {ascii} -append -force.  thanks Ben N

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried the $doc.JOB.SAMPLE.SAMPLETIME but it only gave me the value, is it possible to get the name "SAMPLETIME : Value" ?

Comment: @Leo Yes, you can concatenate anything you like with the value. `'SAMPLETIME : ' + $doc.JOB.SAMPLE.SAMPLETIME` should do the job.